# "Ветер" in genitive - why "ветра", not "ветера"?

Tags: родительный-падеж, беглая-гласная

I am wondering why the genitive case for ветер is ветра instead of "ветера". Is there any rule behind this instance? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disappearing vowel is called a fleeting / mobile vowel («беглая» гласная). Some words have them, most don't. If a noun has a fleeting vowel, then it will obey these rules:

1. A fleeting vowel can only appear between two consonants (**й** being a consonant). It is always the last vowel in the stem of the word. A stem is the part that is left when throwing away any endings: ветер has the stem вет**е**р, кошка has the stem кош**е**к (with a fleeting **-е-**).
2. A word form has a fleeting vowel only if the ending is null or begins with a consonant: люб**о**вь (null) - любви́ (vowel) - люб**о**вью (consonant - phonetically **й**у).
3. If there is a consonant cluster to the left of a vowel, the vowel is kept in all cases: бегл**е́**ц - бегл**е**ца́ (compare to гон**е**ц - гонца́), лж**е**ц - лж**е**ца́.

Fleeting vowels historically formed after the [Fall of the Jers](http://russianmentor.net/gram/mailbag/topics/phon2.htm) ([падение редуцированных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)) in 11-13 centuries AD.

Now the big question is, how does one tell if a word has a fleeting vowel? There is no definitive answer but a few patterns do stand out:

Masculine nouns:

- ending in **-ец**: кон**е́**ц - конца́, па́л**е**ц - па́льца, бо**е́**ц - бойца́;
- ending in **-ень**: па́р**е**нь - па́рня, ко́р**е**нь - ко́рня, ка́м**е**нь - ка́мня, п**е**нь - пня;
- ending in **-ок/-ек/-ёк**: зам**о**к - замка, замоч**е**к - замочка, звер**ё**к - зверька́, ча**ё**к - чайка́;
- ending in **-ей**: мурав**е́**й - муравья́, вороб**е́**й - воробья́, у́л**е**й - у́лья;
- ending in **-ёл**: ор**ё**л - орла́, ос**ё**л - осла́, коз**ё**л - козла́, кот**ё**л - котла́;
- Quite a few odd ones: с**о**н - сна, р**о**т - рта, л**е**в - льва, м**о**х - мха, у́г**о**л - угла́, у́г**о**ль - угля́, etc.

Feminine and neuter nouns may get a fleeting vowel in **genitive plural**:

- consonant + **ка**: ко́шка - кош**е**к, ба́нка - ба́н**о**к, селёдка - селёд**о**к, ко́йка - ко́**е**к;
- consonant + **ня**: ви́шня - виш**е**н, ба́шня - ба́ш**е**н, дере́вня - дерев**е́**нь;
- consonant + **ья**: семья́ - сем**е́**й, статья́ - стат**е́**й, судья́ - су́д**е**й;
- consonant + **ьё**: ружьё - ру́ж**е**й, копьё - ко́п**и**й;
- са́бля - са́б**е**ль, ка́пля - ка́п**е**ль, сопло́ - со́п**е**л, дупло́ - ду́п**е**л;
- **-сло**: ма́сло - мас**е**л, ремесло́ - ремёс**е**л;
- **-дро**: ведро́ - вёд**е**р, бедро́ - бёд**е**р;
- Odd ones: яйцо́ - я**и**ц, ку́кла - ку́кол, серьга́ - сер**ё**г, кочерга́ - кочер**ё**г, в**о**шь - вши.

Notice how **й** is lost in writing but is still pronounced: га́йка - га́ек (га[jе]к), ле́йка - ле́ек (ле[jе]к).

Fleeting vowels also exist in verbs (брать - б**е**ру́, звать - з**о**ву́), adjectives (кра́ткий - кра́т**о**к, ну́жный - ну́ж**е**н), pronouns (в**е**сь - всего́), prefixes (вз**о**браться - взберусь) and prepositions (к нему - к**о** мне).

Outside of these patterns telling if a word has a fleeting vowel is difficult:

- ве́т**е**р - ве́тра
- ка́тер - ка́тера

When in doubt, use a dictionary or [this tool](http://morpher.ru?s=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80).

Comment: See also other questions tagged 'беглая-гласная': https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

No, this missing letter is just an exception. But there are exceptions for some plural nouns' endings like:
Учи́тель - учителя́    (Род. падеж for singular - учи́теля)
Дом -  дома́               (Род. падеж for singular - до́ма)
Вечер - вечера́          (Род. падеж for singular - ве́чера) 
Ветер - ветрá             (Род. падеж for singular - ве́тра)
As you can see in these words the stress syllable also changes. 
Although, if we follow the rules the words should have become "учи́тели", "до́мы" and "ве́черы" - but these words do not sound good.

Answer (score 1):

This [extra](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/) vowel (mobile vowel) may appear in the grammatical cases when a noun has no ending. But you can't say for sure if it does.

In your example this mobile vowel disappears in all cases except nominative, not just genitive.

In my opinion, you should just memorize such words.